# how to access the blog content through shopify API

Tags: api, graphql, shopify, shopify-api, shopify-api-node

I recently created a Shopify Admin account and created a private App to access the Shopify store content from an external app. I called the Shopify blogs API from Postman to fetch the blogs using the API key and password, but I am not able to retrieve the blogs' content.

I called this endpoint for accessing the blogs `https://${API_KEY}:${PASSWORD}@${STORE_NAME}.myshopify.com/admin/api/2021-01/blogs.json`

This is the response I get in the postman:

```
{
    "blogs": [
        {
            "id": 75486953641,
            "handle": "news",
            "title": "News",
            "updated_at": "2021-01-18T04:58:06-08:00",
            "commentable": "no",
            "feedburner": null,
            "feedburner_location": null,
            "created_at": "2021-01-13T05:03:38-08:00",
            "template_suffix": null,
            "tags": "about",
            "admin_graphql_api_id": "gid://shopify/OnlineStoreBlog/75486953641"
        }
    ]
}
```

this actually shows that I have a blog, but it does not show the blog content that I wrote, am I missing something here, How can I actually access the blog content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Blog is a thing. You can have 1, 2 or more. You asked for a blog, you got a blog. A blog is a thing that has zero, one or more articles. I think you want the articles belonging to a blog. So if you want the **content** of a blog, you should look into the **articles** endpoint perhaps? Is that what you are missing?

Comment: yes, thank you it solved the query, I was looking for the article.